# is it possible to reach out of closure scope in php and access variable by reference?

Tags: php, closures

example:

```
$my_var = 'some text';
$my_closure = function($variable_name) {
  //here some magic...
  $$variable_name = 'some other text';
};
$my_closure('my_var');
echo $my_var //-> 'some other text';
```

the only way I know now is by using `compact()` or `use()` in the closure declaration, but compact look like this `extract($my_closure(compact('my_var')));` and use must be done when closure is declared so is not flexible.

Comment: this might not exactly answer your question, but why you don't use return $variable;  or global? or return array if you need some bunch of variables to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the same as any other function, you declare the parameter as [pass-by-reference](http://php.net/references):

```
$my_var = 'some text';
$my_closure = function(&$var) {
  $var = 'some other text';
};
$my_closure($my_var);
echo $my_var."\n";
```

Allowing arbitrary access to the calling scope is far too dangerous though and would lead to too many issues. Closures in languages in general, not just PHP, are designed to be able to access private/local variables in the scope they were defined in (`use()` in PHP), but I can't think of a single one that allows them to arbitrarily access locals in the calling scope (even other scripting languages).

Comment: Very good answer from Matthey Scharley.   To read about php referencing see this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 0):

finally found it and I am baffled that it was so obvious:

```
$outside_var = 'wrong';
$closure = function($var_name,$new_value) {
  global $$var_name; // SO OBVIOUS!!!
  $$var_name = $new_value;
};

echo $outside_var."\n";
$closure('outside_var','right');
echo $outside_var."\n";
```

Unfortunately the limitation is that variable must be declared before closure, otherwise the variable is NULL.

Comment: Please don't do this... do it properly and just pass the variable by reference. Is there some reason you can't do this?

Comment: Why I should not do it ? This is my code and it would be closure in a function so everything is protected from spill. The reason is that I must also know the variable name, so if there was an error I could post a message what variable is wrong.

Comment: Globals are just that: global. Their scope is the entire program. Entirely aside from that, it's harder for tools to track things if you start passing around strings with variable and function names in them and use those as 'references'. Part of the reason that closures were introduced with 5.3 was to try to get away from the so-called 'callback' types used in PHP (strings that happen to contain function names).